# Why does it return entire array in java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, stack, tostring

Hi so im writing a program and i want to return part of an array that does doesnt include null or  0 in it. so the array is originally int and i converted it to string and use this

```
public String toString(){
    // TODO: Return the String with the format of [1,2,3,4] as an example. Have stack items seperated by commas, enclosed inside brackets, and no comma at the end!

    if(top ==0 || a== null )
        return "[ ]";
    String [] d = new String [n];
    for(int r=0; r<n ; r++) {
        //if (r<0 && a[r] != 0)
        d[r] = Integer.toString(a[r]);
    }
    return "[" + String.join("," , d) + "]";


    // This can be removed but is here to prevent the Java error while testing!
}
```

to return the result i wanted but instead of it returning the valued i need it is returing all the values in the array no matter what if statement i am using. so n =256. can someone plz help me my hw is due soon and its the last part thats been bugging me the entire day.

Comment: Share more code please

Comment: Please format the question properly to better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code:

```
for(int r=0; r<n ; r++) {
    if (<anything>)
        d[r] = Integer.toString(a[r]);
}
```

In this code `r` is going to increment on each iteration irrespective of whether the `<anything>` is true or not. So you will be filling values when the condition holds and skipping the other values. This probably is not what you want.

You have a few options. The easiest is to use a `List` instead of an array:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int r=0; r<n ; r++) {
    if (<anything>)
        result.add(Integer.toString(a[r]);
}
```

If you must use an array then you will need to store the number of items separately so that you know how many items that met the condition there are:

```
int itemCount = 0;
for(int r=0; r<n ; r++) {
    if (<anything>)
        d[itemCount++] = Integer.toString(a[r]);
}
```

You can then either use the item count in your print statement or resize the array:

```
d = Arrays.copyOf(d, itemCount);
```

Even easier than all of these is to use a `Stream` to do it all in one statement:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(a)
    .filter(<anything>).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]");
```

Comment: ok thank you ill try those out. But what is the header for <anything>

Comment: <anything> just meant any condition. Such as `a[r] != 0`.

Comment: oh that did not work. i have tried multiple conditions and i still do not get the correct result

Comment: it judt juves me null 256 times

Comment: try using an interactive debugger